# 4 SSL cert-files: what are the differences betwen them? which one(s) should I use?

Tags: azure, ssl, ssl-certificate, azure-web-roles

I issued `SSL` certificate for my domain, let's say it's `example.com` (which includes also the `www.example.com` subdomain). I received the `example_com.zip` file, including these files:

```
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
example_com.crt
```

Using [this guide](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/361/17/how-do-i-convert-crt-file-into-the-microsoft-cer-format) I exported them to their equivalents `cer` files.

What are the differences between the 4 different cert-files? which one(s) should I upload to my `Azure` `webrole`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should import all certificates on your local computer, and then export the final one - example_com.crt - as PFX file (as that's what Azure requires). When you export - make sure to set "include all certificates in certificate path" checkbox - as that's what the other files are. And then you feed example_com.pfx into Azure.

And to answer your question - those other 3 files are [intermediate certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_certificate_authorities) used by your CA.

Comment: nope - for Azure you need PFX: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate/ But if you are on Windows, PFX is just another file type in "Export certificate" window..

Comment: The `pfx` option is grayed out in the certificate's `Details` tab -> `Copy to File...`, and I don't see my domain anywhere in the `certlm` `mmc`

Comment: you need to export it with private key. Here is step-by-step guide: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/

Comment: I don't have the private key :-( how can I obtain it? I used `IIS` to create the `CSR`. Do I need to start the whole process anew with `openssl`? there is no way to somehow use these files?

Comment: if you used IIS to create CSR, then you need to use IIS to complete the certificate request - and then you will have the private key on your PC. Do yourself a favour, read the link I posted: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/#bkmk_iismgr

Comment: I read it but it doesn't work - I get `The requested property value is empty. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80094004)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90066/discussion-between-avs099-and-tal).